# Using HTML in my TextView

Tags: android, html, textview

I want to use HTML in my TextView (sub- and superscript). The problem is, that I only want to use XML when coding my UI elements: I don't want to use `HTML.fromHtml(...);`.

The string I have in my resources is the following code:

```
...
<string name="buttonY1"><![CDATA[<html><i>Y</i><sup>2</sup></html>]]></string>
...
```

The XML code is:

```
...
<TextView android:text="@string/buttonY1"
                      android:textSize="20sp"
                      android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
...
```

When I debug my app, the text shows plain text (with the tags still in it), and not the parsed HTML. Any solutions?

Comment: Why you do not want use HTML.fromHtml()?

Comment: I might, but in my case it doesn't make anything easier. There is more code than the snippets here, and it would take a lot of code to use HTML.fromHtml(). Also, I am just interested if there is any easy way

Comment: seems you have to use HTML.fromHtml(...);.

Comment: Look at the first answer, it looks like I don't have to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple remove the CDATA part, just include the tags as they are e.g.:

```
<string name="lorem_short"><sub>Lorem</sub> ipsum dolor <sup>sit</sup> amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</string>
```